# No incoming messages on whatsapp if internet isn't turned on

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have an HTC and I downloaded my whatsapp from the market place but now I don't receive any incoming messages unless I turn on my internet. Is there a way for me to get my messages without having the internet turned on.

Comment: um... troll question?

Comment: How, pray tell, do you expect to receive messages without network connectivity. Giving the benefit of the doubt here: Do you perhaps mean Wi-Fi?

Comment: The description explicitly says it "uses 3G or Wifi" to communicate with your friends.

Comment: I guess he probably thought that whatsapp would (or should?) function as a SMS client

Comment: Your HTC, huh? Yeah, I wish they'd hurry up and release a second phone.

Comment: @Power-Inside: That's the only logical explanation.

Answer (score 3):

WhatsApp uses Internet to send / receive messages (or images, videos, etc.)! There's no way you can send / receive messages without Internet!!

Quote from [WhatsApp website](http://www.whatsapp.com/):

> WhatsApp Messenger uses the same internet data plan that you use for
>   email and web browsing...